# Товары при бесконечной прокрутке не сортируются php+js

Tags: javascript, php, прокрутка

У меня реализована бесконечная прокрутка  машин есть два файла, by_maker отвечает за саму старину с разметкой ,  damps_loading отвечает за бесконечную прокрутку.
1)код сортировки рабочий , у меня стоит отображение 21 модели на страницу, при первой загрузке при участии кода  by_maker первые 21 машин отсортированы по параметрам, это может быть марка, модели или год . Использована самая  обычная структура if, else.

Код by_maker который отвечает за сортировку
Вот он

```
<?php
                      // Инициализация базового запроса
                      $query = "SELECT * FROM auct_lots_full ";

                      // Инициализация массива для хранения условий WHERE
                      $where = array();

                      // Проверяем наличие параметра и добавляем соответствующее условие
                      if (isset($company)) {
                        $where[] = "company = '$company'";
                      }

                      if (isset($model_name_en)) {
                        $where[] = "model_name_en = '$model_name_en'";
                      }

                      if (isset($model_year_en)) {
                        $where[] = "model_year_en = '$model_year_en'";
                      }

                      // Добавляем условия WHERE к запросу, если есть хотя бы одно условие
                      if (!empty($where)) {
                        $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
                      }

                      $query .= " ORDER BY lot_id DESC LIMIT 21";

                      // Выполняем запрос
                      $get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                      $num_cars = mysqli_num_rows($get_query);



                      if ($num_cars <= 0) {
                        echo "Нет доступных товаров в этой категории.";
                      } else {
                        while ($get_list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) { ?>
```

Далее в этой же страницу идет js code для вызова прокрутки.

```
 var currentScrollHeight = 0;
        var n = <?php echo $num_cars ?>;
        var company = <?php echo (!empty($company) ? json_encode($company) : '""'); ?>;
        var model_name_en = <?php echo (!empty($model_name_en) ? json_encode($model_name_en) : '""'); ?>;
        var model_year_en = <?php echo (!empty($model_year_en) ? json_encode($model_year_en) : '""'); ?>;
        var per_page = 21;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Infinite scroll (dynamic car loading)
            var list = $("#car-infinite-list")[0];
            if (n >= per_page) {
                $(list).addClass("madamada");
            }

            $(window).on("scroll", function () {
                if (n >= per_page) {
                    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
                    var scrollPos = Math.floor($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());
                    var isBottom = scrollHeight - 1000 < scrollPos;

                    if (isBottom && currentScrollHeight < scrollHeight) {
                        console.log("B: " + n);
                        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                list.innerHTML += this.responseText;
                                var newCars = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                                if (newCars.length > 0) {
                                    n += newCars.length;
                                    console.log("A: " + n);
                                } else {
                                    $(list).removeClass("madamada");
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        var url = "damps_loading.php?n=" + n;
                        if (company !== '') {
                            url += "&company=" + encodeURIComponent(company);
                        }
                        if (model_name_en !== '') {
                            url += "&model_name_en=" + encodeURIComponent(model_name_en);
                        }
                        if (model_year_en !== '') {
                            url += "&model_year_en=" + encodeURIComponent(model_year_en);
                        }

                        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        currentScrollHeight = scrollHeight;
                    }
                } else {
                    $(list).removeClass("madamada");
                }
            });
        });
```

Далее покажу файл damps_loading он уже с html разметкой, такая же разметка и в by_maker есть.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('../admin-aj/conn/connectvars.php');

// PHP code start

$n = $_GET['n'] + 1;
$per_page = 21;

// Инициализация базового запроса
$query = "SELECT * FROM auct_lots_full ";

// Инициализация массива для хранения условий WHERE
$where = array();

// Проверяем наличие параметра и добавляем соответствующее условие
if (isset($company)) {
    $where[] = "company = '$company'";
}

if (isset($model_name_en)) {
    $where[] = "model_name_en = '$model_name_en'";
}

if (isset($model_year_en)) {
    $where[] = "model_year_en = '$model_year_en'";
}

// Добавляем условия WHERE к запросу, если есть хотя бы одно условие
if (!empty($where)) {
    $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
}

$query .= " ORDER BY lot_id DESC LIMIT $n, $per_page";

// Выполняем запрос
$get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$num_cars = mysqli_num_rows($get_query);

$cars = array();
if ($num_cars > 0) {
    while ($get_list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_query)) {
        $cars[] = $get_list;
    }
}
?>

<section class="ftco-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-wrap">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            if ($num_cars <= 0) {
                                echo "Нет доступных товаров в этой категории.";
                            } else {
                                foreach ($cars as $get_list) {
                            ?>
                                    <tr class="alert" role="alert">
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="damps_details.php?lot_id=<?php echo $get_list['lot_id']; ?>&cate=<?php echo $get_list['company']; ?>">
                                                <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Details</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['lot_date'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['auction_name'] ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php
                                            $urls = explode('#', $get_list['pics_urls']);
                                            if (isset($urls[1])) {
                                                $second_url = $urls[1];
                                            ?>
                                                <div class="img" style="background-image:"> <img src="<?php echo $second_url; ?>"> </div>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span><?php echo $get_list['company'] ?></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><?php echo  $get_list['model_name_en'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['grade_en'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['model_year_en'] ?>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['mileage_en'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['transmission_en'] ?>&nbsp;KM</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['color_en'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['scores_en'] ?>USD</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['model_type_en'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $get_list['scores_en'] ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                            <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php
// Возвращаем список моделей в формате JSON
echo "<input type='hidden' class='gars' value='$num_cars'>";
?>
```

Я пытаюсь понять в чем может быть ошибка, почему он отдает не отсортированные данные, ведь код сортировки работает. Может есть какие-то отладчики , что-бы как то узнать. И не может ли быть такого, что damps_laoding все делает верно, а js а by_maker перемешивает результаты. Еще вообще в БД у каждого авто есть полк lot_id в начале, по ним он определят авто. И еще я так понимаю проблема в том, что на стороне когда клиент сортирует авто, то сервер на своей стороне не запоминает , что он отсортировал и дает результаты в перемешку. Это относиться даже если выбрана только марка , даже пре выборе 1 значения он уже дает все в разнобой + эти данные повторяются, то есть можно листать бесконечно и результат будет повторяться.
Я приложу фото для наглядности. [image: пример выбран Yanmaar , а при загрузки, вываливаются рандомные модели, и мало того, опять пролистать до низу они опять загрузиться, те же самые.]

Comment: Это совершенно неправильный подход - выводить одно и то же разными обработчиками. Нужна одна функция, которая на входе будет получать параметры поиска и страницу, брать данные из БД, формировать  итоговый `html` и возвращать его. Изначально она вернёт первую страницу (первую 21 запись), затем `js` будет засылать следующий номер страницы и параметры и получать итоговый код. Также `js` должен засылать `POST`-запрос (например с FormData-объектом) вместо GET-запроса с GET-параметрами, получать итоговый кусок `html`-кода и вставлять после предыдущего. Всё будет гораздо чище и проще.